# Iterate a command of a ArcGIS extension: batch using Python

Tags: python, loops, batch-file, batch-processing, arcgis

I am trying to iterate in ArcGIS for a number of shapefiles a function, which is loaded as a small extension (one single function in the extension):
http://www.jennessent.com/arcgis/conefor_inputs.htm

I cannot drag and drop the function to the model builder. Maybe it is feasible using a loop in Python?

I am working with ArcGIS 9.3 or 10

THANKS!
Nigel

Answer (score 0):

Will your users have ArcPy?  This will make it easier - I would suggest something like this:

```
def perform(fclass):
   ...do whatever you do to each FC here...

FCList = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
FCList = FCList.split(";")
for FC in FCList:
   arcpy.AddMessage("Working on "+FC)
   perform(FC)
```

Remember though - ArcPy is only available in 10.0 or 10.1, not 9.3, so it'll be different for 9.3, I think you'll make a "gp" and use it to do your geoprocessing.

Hope this helps some -
JimF